# What's the difference in the film between sputtering deposition and an ebeam evaporator?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, experimental-technique

I know the differences between the two deposition techniques, but what about the difference in the properties of the resulting films? All things being equal (such as substrate temperature), would there be an intrinsic difference between sputtered or e-beam evaporated metal films in such properties as as thickness uniformity or stress?

Answer (score 2):

Sputtering deposition is not normally preformed at ultra high vacuum pressures, thus the films tend to be polycrystalline while e-beam evaporated metal films could be done at much lower pressures resulting in a more uniform film, even single crystalline depending on other conditions like the substrate, lattice mismatch and so on. This is just one difference.